# How to get duplicate substring and add remaining attach integer value of substring in DB2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

My scenario is that i have duplicate substring with string in column like

> col1

|QWERT-1  |

|QWERT-3  |

|QWERT-12|

I want to get outout column as like

```
QWERT
```

|    16     |

i.e addition of 1+3+12 of duplicate substring(QWERT)and QWERT set as column name

How can I do it using DB2 SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(SUBSTR(t.YourColumn, LOCATE('-',t.YourColumn)+1) as INT)) as sum_total
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: but I get error (An unexpected response was received from the data source: Invalid character string format for type INTEGER.)note->col 1 value store as char data type

Comment: Then not all the data is like you posted. Edit your question and provide all the possibilties of data and what you want out of it. @AmrutaRaut

Comment: No problem :). Kindly accept this answer . @AmrutaRaut

Comment: Hi sagi ,I have one more query is that how to set QWERT as a column name

Comment: Dynamically ? Or specifically `QWERT` ? . You can change `as sum_total` to `as QWERT` @AmrutaRaut

Comment: Hi sagi I have update the qurey but it get all values for sum,In my col 1 ,duplicate and non duplicates values are here.I want add only duplicate substring values

Comment: You're using a `GROUP BY` ? If so, you can use the `HAVING` clause, something like `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` @AmrutaRaut

Comment: No, actually i am new for for DB2 sql, I am not using a GROUP BY,thank u for response to correct me

Comment: I tried it a lot using having clause,but how to fetch only duplicate sub string or before ' - ' string?